# What's the most succinct way to find and replace a string in a collection of files using standard unix tools?

Tags: unix, sed, grep

What's the most succinct way to find and replace a string in a collection of files using standard unix tools?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I usually do it:

```
find [whatever-files-you-want] | xargs sed -i s/string/replacement/g
```

Comment: don't you mead sed -i -e 's/string/replacement/g'

Comment: Works without `-e` as well, no?

Comment: Some versions of `sed` require the `-e`. Some require that an extension be supplied as an argument to `-i`, while for some it's optional.